# Data is not coming in laravel 5.4 after using timestamp in query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

Data is not coming when comparing current time between 2 times to fetch data in Laravel. Both times are saved in the database as timestamp and in query also I am using timestamp. Below is the code i wrote:-

```
$current_date = strtotime(date('d-m-Y H:i:s'));
        
$bookings = MachineBooking::with('userDetail')->where('machine_id', $machine_id)->where('time_from', '>=', $current_date)->where('time_to', '<', $current_date)->get();
```

"**time_from**" and "**time_to**" both timestamps are saved in bigint format in database. I entered timestamp using search option in direct database also still data did not come. Can someone please tell me where i am making mistake.

Comment: No only you are using `strtotime(date('d-m-Y H:i:s'));` instead of just `now()->toDateTimeString()`, but also you are using a nearly 6 years old framework where there were a lot of optimizations and there is new staff on Laravel 9.x (nearly Laravel 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should swap the `time_from` to `<=` and `time_to` to `>`, and try

```
$bookings = MachineBooking::with('userDetail')
    ->where('machine_id', $machine_id)
    ->where('time_from', '<=', $current_date) # changed
    ->where('time_to', '>', $current_date) # changed
    ->get();
```

Comment: thanks for reply. It is working for me. But how is it possible. Current time should be greater than start time and less than end time. You swapped it. And it worked too. Can you tell in details what actually happened.

Comment: It is not possible both `time_from` and `time_to`  greater than and equal to the current time.

Answer (score 0):

You not describe what database you use. But maybe you can change to `Y-m-d H:i:s` format:

```
$current_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

but `strtotime` is return int not bigint.

Comment: I am using  MySQL for database

Answer (score 0):

I hope I will help you
firstly You must cast the date in Model MachineBooking

```
protected $casts = ['time_from' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s',time_to =>'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s'];
```

secondly
cast current date  with same format of time_from and time_to

```
$current_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code with:

```
$current_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`time_from` and `time_to` are formatted date not a int . But your `$current_date` is int with using strtotime method
Just take strtotime method:

```
$current_date =date('d-m-Y H:i:s'); 
$bookings = MachineBooking::with('userDetail')->where('machine_id', $machine_id)->where('time_from', '>=', $current_date)->where('time_to', '<', $current_date)->get()
```

Comment: I have already told that both are stored in bigint format